# how to store simply multi array in session laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

i store one array in to session('cart') last click [add to cart] , when i add another array in session('cart'), but it store one array then session can not save both. 
help me !

```
public function addtocart(Request $req,$id){

  $product = _prod::find($id)->toArray();
  $item = [
         'name' => $product['pName'],
         'description' => $product['pDesc'],
         'price' => $product['pPrice'],
         ];

  $cart = [
          'qtyTotal' => 0,
          'priceTotal' => 0,
          'item' => [$item]
         ];

   $req->session()->put('cart',$cart);
   $a = session()->get('cart');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
    $req->session()->put('cart',$cart);
    $a = session()->get('cart');
    dd($a);
```

to this:

```
    $cartvalues[] = $cart;
    $req->session()->put('cart',$cartvalues);
    $a = session('cart');
    dd($a);
```

because you keep overwriting the previous value inside the session cart

Answer (score 0):

Here you are overwriting `cart` variable in session every time you add a new item. So store cart items as an array and add item to array. Code should be:

```
public function addtocart(Request $req, $id) {
    $product = _prod::find($id)->toArray();
    $item = [
        'name' => $product['pName'],
        'description' => $product['pDesc'],
        'price' => $product['pPrice'],
    ];

    $cart = [
        'qtyTotal' => 0,
        'priceTotal' => 0,
        'item' => [$item]
    ];

    $cartItems = session()->get('cart');
    if (empty($cartItems)) {
        $cartItems = [];
    }
    $cartItems[] = $cart;
    $req->session()->put('cart', $cartItems);
    return view($cartItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example to update your cart in your case

`
    public function addtocart(Request $req,$id){
        //return redirect('Resouce/product');

```
    $product = _prod::find($id)->toArray();
    $item = [
        'name' => $product['pName'],
        'description' => $product['pDesc'],
        'price' => $product['pPrice'],
    ];
    if($req->session()->has('cart')){
        $oldCart = $req->session()->get('cart');
        $newCart = [
            'qtyTotal' => 0,
            'priceTotal' => 0,
            'item' => array_merge($item,$oldCart['item'])
        ];
        $req->session()->put('cart',$newCart);
    }

    $cart = [
        'qtyTotal' => 0,
        'priceTotal' => 0,
        'item' => [$item]
    ];


    $req->session()->put('cart',$cart);
    $a = session()->get('cart');
    dd($a);
}`
```